# MySQL: How to delete single table that is connected via foreign key?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am generating a database schema via Java and want to drop only the tables I made changes to, in order to spare me from entering all the data again (or importing it from a manually updated dump).

But since nearly all the tables are connected via foreign keys in one way or another, MySQL-Workbench won't allow me to drop those single tables and gives me the following error:

```
ERROR 1217: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
SQL Statement:
drop table `mydb`.`mytable`
```

I am using MySQL 5.6 with InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried settings `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` to 0 before dropping your tables?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I get the same error. I added it to my question.

Comment: You tried `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` before dropping the table, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a cascaded DELETE statement. In the schema navigator, right-click on your table and select "Delete with References" from either "Send to SQL Editor" or "Send to Clipboard" and then execute the generated query.